# Unable to plot keys and values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matplotlib

I have a list of dicts as follows:

```
collect
Out[60]: 
[{'A01': 0.07,
  'A02': 0.1,
  'A03': 0.08,
  'A04': 0.11,
  'A05': 0.05,
  'A06': 0.09,
  'A07': 0.09,
  'A08': 0.15,
  'A09': 0.17,
  'A10': 0.09},
 {'A01': 0.07,
  'A02': 0.07,
  'A03': 0.02,
  'A04': 0.22,
  'A05': 0.09,
  'A06': 0.06,
  'A07': 0.07,
  'A08': 0.26,
  'A09': 0.09,
  'A10': 0.04}]
```

I need to plot these as bar charts, with the first 10 keys having label 'A', ad 2nd 10 keys having label 'B'. I tried plotting it with matplotlib using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
X_AS=[]
Y_AS=[]
for i in range(len(collect)):
    x_as=collect[i].keys()  
    y_as=collect[i].values()
    X_AS.append(x_as)
    Y_AS.append(y_as)
Xlist = pd.Series(v for v in X_AS)
Ylist = pd.Series(v for v in Y_AS)
plt.bar(Xlist,Ylist, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'dict_values'
```

Can somebody help me out here? Thannks.

Comment: please show a complete code

Comment: hi, This is the whole code for plotting that I have tried.

Comment: No it ain't. where `X_AS` is declared? `Y_AS`, `pd`?

Comment: You're missing something, like defining `X_AS` and `Y_AS`. I guess you're running in python 3, then the `keys()` and `values()` methods don't return a a list and you should do something like `x_as=list(collect[i].keys())`.

Comment: Hi, I've edited it. Pd wasn't necessary because I had imported it before elsewhere.

Comment: But you didn't show that import :-(

Comment: right sorry, anyway ca anything be done here?

Comment: @Ignacio, I get this error: TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars, while trying to plot it as per your suggestion.

Comment: I cant' reproduce your error. All I get is *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seq'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the plot you are after. Pandas is not used at all.
You should be able to modify this to get the desired output.

If instead you wanted to use the dictionary keys directly you could look into using the 'categories' functionality of matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# use these to generate positions and add legend labels
labels = {0:'A',
         1:'B'}

# this sets the position of each set of bars
offsets = {0:-0.15,
          1:+0.15}

# define the main positions
main_positions = [i for i in range(len(collect[0]))]

## loop  each set of data in the dict using the defined labels
for label in labels:

    # generate list of values to plot
    vals = [collect[label][i] for i in sorted(collect[label])]

    # plot the data and set the tick labels
    plt.bar([main_positions[i] + offsets[label]+1 for i in main_positions],vals,width=0.3,label=labels[label])

## tidy the xticks and add legend
plt.xticks([i+1 for i in main_positions])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot]